# Assembly 64 bits function a*b+c/d-(e-f)%(g+h)

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I need to solve this function in assembly but I have a problem with modulo. I have no idea why but it gives very strange results.

C++ code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
extern "C" __int64 suma(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h);
int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1, d = 1, e = 1, f = 1, g = 1, h = 1;
    int wynik = suma(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h);
    std::cout << wynik;
    
}
```

assembly code

```
.CODE
_DATA SEGMENT
_DATA ENDS
_TEXT SEGMENT
PUBLIC suma
suma PROC
    push rbp;
    mov rbp, rsp;
    imul rcx, rdx; // a * b
    mov rax, r8; // c
    xor rdx, rdx;
    div r9; // c/d
    mov r10, [rbp + 6 * 8]; //e
    sub r10, [rbp + 7 * 8]; // e-f
    mov r11, [rbp + 8 * 8]; // g
    add r11, [rbp + 9 * 8]; //g + h
    add rcx, rax; // a * b + c / d
    sub rcx, r10; // a * b + c / d - e - f
    mov rdx, 0;
    mov rax, rcx; 
    idiv r11;
    mov rax, rdx;
    pop rbp;
ret
suma ENDP
_TEXT ENDS
END
```

Comment: What is that "strange result"? Also, in your formula, does the modulo apply to `(e-f)` only or are you missing parentheses?

Comment: The C declaration specifies `int` for the parameters, but the asm code assumes int64.  Okayish for the arguments passed through the registers, but not the ones passed through the stack.

Comment: @HansPassant: It's not really ok for the register args earlier because this is signed `int`; The caller won't have wasted time sign-extending them to 64-bit, so usually they'll just end up zero-extended if the high halves don't hold garbage (e.g. if the C source truncated a 64-bit result that it calculated in the same register).  Or did you say "okayish" because this function is using unsigned `div` as well, so it's assuming non-negative?  Anyway, yes, it's definitely not fully correct even for register args, but those will work with a caller that passes non-negative constants. Stack is broken

Comment: It would appear that your suma assembly function is finding (a * b+c/d-(e-f))%(g+h), i.e. an extra set of parentheses around all of the expression prior to the modulo operator. Instead, the conventional order of precedence should require the calculation of (e-f)%(g+h) before performing the subtraction from a * b+c/d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but when you have to write something in assembly, it is often a good idea to first have a look at what the compiler produces.

I'm not sure why you have an `__int64` return type when you assign it anyway to an `int`, but I'll respect your given function prototype.

```
__int64 suma(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h);
```

The compiler I'll use is GCC in Linux, but your register usage follows the Windows ABI, so I'll change the declaration as follows.

```
__attribute__((ms_abi))
long long suma(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f, int g, int h);
```

Now put your one line of code in the body, and see the output with optimization (`-O3`).

```
{
    return a * b + c / d - (e - f) % (g + h);
}

suma:
        mov     eax, r8d
        imul    ecx, edx
        mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rsp+64]
        add     r8d, DWORD PTR [rsp+56]
        cdq
        idiv    r9d
        add     ecx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+40]
        sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp+48]
        cdq
        idiv    r8d
        sub     ecx, edx
        movsx   rax, ecx
        ret
```

Finally make it look better, a bit more like human-written.

```
suma:
        imul    ecx, edx
        mov     eax, r8d
        cdq
        idiv    r9d
        add     ecx, eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp + 40]
        sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp + 48]
        cdq
        mov     r8d, DWORD PTR [rsp + 56]
        add     r8d, DWORD PTR [rsp + 64]
        idiv    r8d
        sub     ecx, edx
        movsx   rax, ecx
        ret
```

Also, as a personal opinion, don't blindly write

```
push rbp;
mov rbp, rsp;
```

at the entry of every function. Cases where this part is necessary is rare in a practical sense.